How can I get Sumo Graphical Interface - Edit coloring scheme - Street - byLiveEdgeData to work again?
My goal is to create a heatmap of my simulation.
To do that, I used 'Edit coloring scheme - Street - byLiveEdgeData' -> entered to have SUMO collect data for each edge as it was entered.
However, at one point (to try to save time), I tried to save the setting in my registry.
Since then, the entire map is permanently in NoData regarding edges if I use this mode, and 'byLiveEdgeData' present an empty array of choice, so I can't do it again
I tried restarting my computer, using other maps...

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
